# How to solve chain of redirects

Tags: google, redirects, authentication, redirect-chain

I have WordPress site where we use alias `www.example.com/login` to have nice login URL so it redirects user to standard WordPress login URL which is `wp-login.php`.
For the authentication we use service external to WordPress so a plugin redirects user immediately to login form hosted by the service on `login.example.com`. The service further redirects user to authentication server.

Looks like we have chain of redirects that Google doesn't like. How should we deal with it? We'd like Google to know about `/login` page and stop there.

Comment: I'm not sure it would work, but you could try A) give the login page and standard WP login page new URLs to give it a fresh start with Google, B) add meta robots nofollow tag to the nice login page, so Google wouldn't try to follow the links, C) add a meta robots noindex tag to the new WP login page, so if Google ignores it if it does find it. This should make Google ignore the redirects chain. It shouldn't hurt, but you might want to keep both versions for a while. If it does, you can add a 301 redirect from the current nice login URL to the new one.

Answer (score 2):

### Resolving the chain or redirects is important, but it will not convince Google to index a 301 page.

The example.com/login needs to redirect to the correct destination which is login.example.com.

Having it redirect to a wp-login.php and then redirect again to login.example.com does not give you anything it only adds slowness to the site. These redirects are handled under the hood, the user does not know he is redirected to wp-login.php ... he only knows he is redirected to login.example.com after waiting.

But chaining 301 is slower because it opens a https connection to the wp-login.php (which depending on architecture can take several hundred milliseconds) and wp-login.php sends them to another URL to start up a new https connection which depending on architecture can take ...

### Google and 301s / login pages

Google is not likely to index any of these pages because they lack original unique content. And if Google were to index it they may hold it against you because it would be thin content. You may want to consider just placing a noindex tag on it ... login.example.com may already have noindexed it ...

If you really want the page which is a 301 page to be indexed, (normally it is removed from search) you would need to have many links pointing at it as the correct URL. But if indexed and a user clicks on it from the Google results, they are not going to be looking to see that the URL is nice.

### There may be more redirects you don't know about?

Generally, three redirects are safe, maybe a shorturl.com/sdsf ... [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login) then ... example.com/login then ... wp-login.php ... then to the correct login. You may have some redirects you don't know about slowing things down ... ... ... ... ... after five redirects the browser just gives up.

Or something like.

example.com/login ... (redirect by apache, directory needs the /) ... example.com/login/ ... (redirect by ???) ... example.com/wp-login.php ... (redirect by php) ... login.example.com ... (redirect by apache because needs the /) ... login.example.com/

### Performance

If the servers are http/1 it may remove nearly a second from the time of hitting the login button till the first byte of data. http/2 is better but only on the same domain ... example.com/login to example.com/wp-login /// login.example.com it needs to negotiate a new SSL.

[image]